# Typescript convert date to string like this "20140127T224000Z"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I convert a Date object to string like this: "20140127T224000Z"

I have Date object `selectedTime`

When I do `selectedTime.toISOString()` I get

"2018-10-18T16:00:00.000Z"

Then, I apply replace function:

```
var date = selectedTime.toISOString().replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','');
```

but it doesnt work for some reason, returns

[image]

I tried to add mo replace functions, but I still get the same result, for some reason, the "-" or the ":" are not removed

[image]

Using regex, doesnt work either

[image]

Here is the code snippet in typescript:

```
    onTimeSelected(selectedTime: Date, events) {
        var date = selectedTime.toISOString().replace('-','').replace('-','').replace(':','').replace(':','').replace('.','');
        var redirectTo = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?dates=' + date + '/' + date;
        window.open(redirectTo, '_blank');
    }
```

**OK, I will keep it simple, how do you explain this:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder about the use case for this. Are there programs that accept `20140127T224000Z` but not the ISO standard?

Comment: google calendar

Comment: I dont understand why simple string.replace is not working

Comment: @monstro as explained in an answer, replace only replace the first occurrence found if you give a string as parameter. Because the string parameter it's converted to a basic regular expression, and a regular expression without 'global' `g` specifier will match only once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Check my second screenshot, I applied replace several times, same result, debugger doesnt lie

Comment: @monstro I cannot copy paste the code you use in your debugger since it's an image, but using two `replace(':', '')` works fine for me in my dev console. `(new Date()).toISOString().replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','');` outputs `"201810-16T1453:23401Z"`, whereas `(new Date()).toISOString().replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','').replace(':', '');` outputs `"201810-16T145351936Z"` . (Chrome 69)

Comment: @monstro debugger *can* lie ;) . For instance, Chrome dev console evaluates objects / arrays lazily. So you could maybe use several console.log, and at the time you look each object you displayed, it's not the old version you wanted to see, but a newer version modified (just giving an example of possible source of confusion)

Comment: who voted to close ???? I clearly say that it doesnt work, not here not on your url

Comment: debugger doesnt lie, i see that then I run the app

Comment: Can you make it an [MCVE]? Did you read the link I provided?

Comment: I dont understnad whats the problem with replace function, I dont want to use Re3gex, replace must work, but it doesnt

Comment: as already said to you in another comment, `replace` uses a regex internally anyway. If you copy paste the code I gave in my comment with two `replace(':', '')` in a JavaScript console, it works fine, you can test it. 

Other have provided you snippets that give the correct output as well, you can just click the execute button. If this is something is not working in your case, then provide the code that doesn't work in the question itself (not in a screenshot please).

Comment: I dont want to use regex

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you show us, see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jL8wbpdc/). Maybe watch is lying to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you supply [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a `String` as its first parameter, only the first occurence will be replaced.

You need to pass a Regex with the **g**lobal flag instead :

```
var date = selectedTime.toISOString().replace(/[-:.]/g,'');
```

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Oops :3

Comment: Check my second screenshot, I applied replace several times, still same problem

Comment: `date.toISOString().replace(/\W/gi, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var date = selectedTime.toISOString().replace(/[-:.]/g,'');
```

instead. If you want you can add this definition and then use it:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (oldValue, newValue) {
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/2307070
    var sanitizedOldValue = oldValue.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    return this.replace(new RegExp(sanitizedOldValue, 'g'), newValue);
}

var date = new Date().toISOString().replaceAll('-','').replaceAll('.','').replaceAll(':','');

console.log(date);
```

Comment: @monstro `replace('str', '')` build a regex internally but it'll stop at first match. Using the `g` modifier, it'll replace all occurences